# How to remove border around terminal vim

Tags: vim, terminal

I'm using terminal vim with the solarized-light theme for both vim and my terminal. If I try and use for example a dark colour scheme for my terminal a dark border appears around my vim window as shown in the image below.

Is there a setting I can change to remove this border, or reduce its width to 0?

[image: Terminal vim window border]

Comment: I'd expect this is a function of your window manager and terminal app

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that from Vim and your terminal emulator doesn't expose an option for that either.

So… use the same background color.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with vim it's a terminal background. There's no simple solution. Use the same background color or change a font. Some fonts with certain sizes ideally fit into terminal width and height. Bitstream font works for me.